# Is there a way to adjust the vertical position of accent above a greek letter in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, accents, greek, tilde

I'm trying to write phi with a wide tilde on top in order to indicate an estimate in statistics, but the tilde are by default clear above the letter, like so:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to lower the tilde, or maybe even allowing it to cross the top of phi if necessary. I will be using

[image].

And it is quite ugly at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're happy with the tilde crossing the bar of the phi, you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wtphi}{%
  \mspace{2mu}%
  \widetilde{\mspace{-2mu}\smash[t]{\phi}}%
}

\begin{document}
$\widetilde\phi$\quad $\widetilde{\Delta\widetilde{\phi}}$

$\wtphi$\quad $\widetilde{\Delta\wtphi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not crossing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wtphi}{%
  \mspace{2mu}%
  \widetilde{\mspace{-2mu}\rule{0pt}{1.3ex}\smash[t]{\phi}}%
}

\begin{document}
$\widetilde\phi$\quad $\widetilde{\Delta\widetilde{\phi}}$

$\wtphi$\quad $\widetilde{\Delta\wtphi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use **`amsmath`** package (for example, it conflicts with other packages), there is another way to do that

```
\newcommand{\wtphi}{%
  \hspace{0.111em}%
  \widetilde{\hspace{-0.251em}\rule{0pt}{1.3ex}\smash{\gvt\phi}}%
}
```